# How to FULLY suppress errors

Tags: php, error-handling, gd

In my production configuration, an error handler emails the administrator and kills the script for all errors.

Then in my application I am using `imagecreatefromstring` which you must use warning suppression (`@`) to test the output.

Here is a test case:

```php
<?php
// This is the production config file
set_error_handler(function ($number, $message, $file, $line, $vars = null) {
    echo 'EMAILING ADMIN';
    exit(1);
}, E_ALL);

// This is the application
$image = 'SOME INVALID IMAGE';
$imageResource = @imagecreatefromstring($image);
if ($imageResource === false) {
    echo 'BAD IMAGE';
} else {
    echo 'GOOD IMAGE';
}
```

I am hoping that because the warning is suppressed, the error handler will be suppressed. But instead, the application crashes ("EMAILING ADMIN") rather than proceeding past the suppressed (`@`) statement.

Is there a workaround the application can use here to avoid crashing?

Comment: Why do you have to suppress `imagecreatefromstring` to test this function? Seems very strange to me

Comment: Yup, that's PHP

Answer (score 0):

Use this workaround in the application code:

```php
set_error_handler(null);
$imageResource = @imagecreatefromstring($image);
restore_error_handler();
```